# How to attach visual studio to a process with ssh that has been started as Root?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster

I am writing an app on raspbian buster lite with .net core 3.1 and I need to start the app with sudo to have access to gpio.

Now I want to debug the app by attaching visual studio to the process.

If I start the process without "sudo" I am able to attach my debugger to the process..

But since I start the app with "sudo" (root) I'm unable to attach my debugger via ssh.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to connect as root. So in the "debug application" dialog, in the "connection target" field (where it currently says something like `pi@192.168.1.40`) change this to `root@192.168.1.40`. You'll be promted for the root password, which should be the same as for the pi user. If that doesn't work, ask google on how to allow root access by ssh on the Pi. This might need aditional configuration, but I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 2):

A step by step to make it works:
Connect to the RaspberryPi with ssh or use the keyboard and console

write :

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find the line "PermitRootLogin" and replace it like this :

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
 Then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Create a password for root :

```
sudo passwd root
```

then reboot with

```
sudo reboot
```

it's done with the raspberry!

---

In visual studio:
Go to **Debug/Options/Cross Platform**

Add the ssh connection with the root username and the password you just created.
Have fun!

Comment: Why reboot in the end?
`sudo systemctl restart sshd.service` won't work in raspbian?